# How to create a stacked area chart with logarithmic (log) scale using Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have two series of data points.  I'd like to generate a stacked area chart using Highcharts JS (javascript library).  This is simple.

However, now I want to use logarithmic scale for the Y-Axis, because for some months, the
data points are very high.

The problem is: in the chart generated, the area below the bottom line is not shaded as it should be when normal y-axis is used.

Here's the code I have:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            type: 'area',
            renderTo: 'container'
        },  

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May',
                         'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },  

        yAxis: {
            type: 'logarithmic'
        },  
        plotOptions: {
          area: {
            stacking: 'normal'
          }   
        },  
        series: [{
            data: [10, 29, 45, 1200, 25, 19, 70],
        },{ 
            data: [5, 10, 30, 800, 20, 30, 20],
        }   
                ]   

    }); 
});
```

You can try it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/CK8vf/

I think the problem could be the min value of Y is 1, not 0, which is not allowed for logarithmic scale.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove your plotOptions settings. For some reason the stacking: 'normal' appears to put the two data series on different scales. Without that, you will get the fill under both.

So:

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        type: 'area',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },  

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May',
                     'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },  

    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic'
    },  
    series: [{
        data: [10, 29, 45, 1200, 25, 19, 70],
    },{ 
        data: [5, 10, 30, 800, 20, 30, 20],
    }   
            ]   

}); 
});
```